# Docker-compose. Как использовать ID реплики в качестве переменной?

Tags: docker-compose

Хочу создать много реплик, но при этом, задавать статические IP-адреса для контейнеров.
Можно ли использовать текущий ID реплики для использования в качестве Х в IP-адресе?

```
services:

 user:
  build: user/
  deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 250
  networks:
   dockervlan:
    ipv4_address: 192.168.1.X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий ответ: нельзя

Более развёрнутый адрес: это невозможно.

Сворм использует специальный тип сетей `overlay` и за вас решает, как разворачивать реплики. Каждая реплика получает адрес последовательно. Причем, если реплика завершается, сварм стартует новый инстанс и присваивает следующий свободный адрес.

Сеть конфигурируется не так, как вы написали. Должно быть что-то вроде

```
 user:
  build: user/
  deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 250
   networks:
    - dockervlan

networks:
  dockervlan:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

Пример.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

ENTRYPOINT ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:'
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  ifconfig:
    image: try-ifconfig
    build: .
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 5
    networks:
      - vlan

networks:
  vlan:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

Сборка и тестирование докера в индивидуальном режиме:

```
docker-compose up
WARNING: Some services (ifconfig) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Building ifconfig
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> 9c6f07244728
Step 2/2 : ENTRYPOINT ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:'
 ---> Running in 9ffe1fcad5ce
Removing intermediate container 9ffe1fcad5ce
 ---> e84bd8313bab

Successfully built e84bd8313bab
Successfully tagged try-ifconfig:latest
WARNING: Image for service ifconfig was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating try-docker_ifconfig_1 ... done
Attaching to try-docker_ifconfig_1
ifconfig_1  |           inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
try-docker_ifconfig_1 exited with code 0
```

Теперь запустим с сворме:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml ipaddr
Ignoring unsupported options: build

Creating network ipaddr_vlan
Creating service ipaddr_ifconfig
```

и посмотрим логи

```
docker service logs ipaddr_ifconfig

ipaddr_ifconfig.3.i4risrg4wg7x@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.3.pyvgtkgt29g8@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.2.umbom0a5ns1b@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.12  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.1.sqlu7lm9f7ng@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.2.ta289m7u22w1@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.4.o4gv8qqm1vud@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.1.fznrkyx95z7n@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.4.9p8519der88y@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.5.2e8ntp5au9iw@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.5.ltzi4s4nukmd@server1    |           inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Видите? Как только инстанс завершается, сворм рестартует и назначает новый адрес. После того как закончатся адреса в подсети сварм начнёт назначать адреса с начала

```
ipaddr_ifconfig.4.tycpevwxvdi0@server    |           inet addr:192.168.1.252  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.1.9m9hfe4kmwix@server    |           inet addr:192.168.1.253  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.5.l1ujy4kpr8ua@server    |           inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.2.c10fypf8yqfv@server    |           inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
ipaddr_ifconfig.4.sl3fniknnycn@server    |           inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Но главный вопрос в другом. ЗАЧЕМ?

Сама идея сворма в том, что докер запускает толпу идентичных инстансов и балансирует нагрузку между ними. Ключевое слово - идентичные. Это просто толпа рабочих, которые обрабатывают запросы, а сворм сам выбирает кому перенаправлять запросы. Они не должны различаться между собой или привязываться к каким-либо уникальным параметрам.

Если вам нужен уникальный инстанс, нужно конфигурировать отдельный сервис в `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: А если использовать номер реплики для другой цели - вот например надо передать в java приложение номер, отвечающий за номер партиции в кафке. Есть способ это сделать в виде подстановки там переменной?

Comment: @asten, если инстансу нужно что-то передать, то это нужно делать не средствами докера. Для докера все реплики равнозначны, параметры у них равны

Comment: благодарю за ответ. А есть совет насчет того, каким способом можно передать такие параметры? Городить отдельные стартеры в контейнере, которые куда-то обратятся, получат свои идентификаторы и потом уже стартанут функциональные инстансы с нужным параметром для кафки?